# Twitter Bootstrap Dropcaps color change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This code renders the number 1 in red as a drop cap

```
        <p><span class="dropcap">1</span> <strong> First point </strong></p>
```

Id like to make the drop cap number 1 green.  How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised this hasn't been answered yet, sorry for the late reply.

You can override any CSS behaviour with your own css. In your own css file:

```
.dropcap {
   color: #006600; /* or whatever shade of green you want */
}
```

If you don't want to override every dropcap colour, then you can do something like:

```
.green {
   color: #660000; 
}
```

and then modify your html to the following:

```
<p><span class="dropcap green">1</span> <strong> First point </strong></p>
```